# How do find hashlist of edition NFTs on Solana?

Tags: anchor, transactions

Hey I need help with this question. How can I find this?

Answer (score 1):

See metaplex `Mint Account List ("Hash List")` doc.

https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/mint-lists